# Expressing $\pi(x) = \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$, where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials

Tags: analytic-number-theory

In Tom Apostol's *Analytic Number Theory* book there is a problem which states:

- That there do not exists polynomials $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ such that $$\pi(x) = \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$.

I tried this problem, but couldn't find a solution. Here is what i attempted. Since $\pi(x) \sim x\log{x}$ as $x \to \infty$, i saw what happens to the Right hand side $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ as $x \to \infty$. I couldn't conclude anything. If there are interesting proof's for this result, i shall be happy to see it.

Comment: Note that in fact $\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\log x}$ (in particular it is less than $x$ for sufficiently large $x$, not greater than $x$!)  Both of the answers so far seem to have taken the OP literally at his word, so seem to require minor modifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you've already gotten the answer. By asymptotic considerations, we must have $\deg P(x) > \deg Q(x)$. Moreover, if we have $\deg P(x) = \deg Q(x) + 1$, then we have 
$$
\frac{\pi(x) Q(x)}{P(x)} \sim \log x \frac{xQ(x)}{P(x)},
$$
but the $xQ(x)/P(x)$ is asymptotic to the ratio of the leading coefficients, so this can't be asymptotic to $1$, i.e. $P(x)/Q(x)$ grows too slowly. On the other hand, if $\deg P(x) = \deg Q(x)+2$, then we similarly see that $P(x)/Q(x)$ grows too quickly to be asymptotic to $x \log x$.

Comment: It also seems that i am not able to finish things off.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT** $\ $ A rational function is asymptotic to $\rm\ x^n,\ $ for some $\rm\ n \in \mathbb Z\:.\ $ But $\rm\ x \log(x)\ $ lies strictly between $\rm\ x\ $ and $\rm x^2$ asymptotically, i.e. $\rm\ (x\ log(x))/x = log(x)\to\infty,\ \ x^2/(x log(x)) = x/log(x)\to \infty$

Comment: How does what you say here, that $\rm\ (x\ log(x))/x = log(x)\to\infty,\ \ x^2/(x log(x)) = x/log(x)\to \infty$ imply that $x \log x$ is not rational?

Comment: @Henry Asymptotically, $\rm\,x\log(x)\,$ is strictly stronger than $\,x\,$ but strictly weaker than $\,x^2.\,$ No rational function has this property, since it is asymptotic to $\,x^n\,$ for some integer $\,n.\ $

Comment: would it change anything if $\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\log x}$?

Comment: @Henry Similarly, that's strictly between $\,x^0\,$ and $\,x^1.\ $  Note I'm using a rougher equivalence where $\,x^n\,$ and $\,c x^n\ (0\ne c\in\Bbb R)\,$ are considered equivalent.